# Memory management (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management, allocation

I have a class `AudioInfo` which contains some `NSString` objects.

In `main()` I create (allocate) some `AudioInfo` object.

Later in `main()` I want to have the second `AudioInfo` object with the same `NSString` objects.

I `init` the second one with `NSStrings` from the first one.

Question:

Should I retain the first `AudioInfo` object to have them both with retain count = 1 after creating (allocating) the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `AudioInfo` should simply `copy` the string properties to its ivars (you should be declaring your `NSString` properties `copy` by default) and each instance would manage its own references. You then release the `AudioInfo` instances when you are finished using them. That's all there is to it.

Comment: well, and what if I can't use `copy`?

Comment: I want to use `init` method and at least one `NSStrings` will be different

Comment: @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *artist; I should do this way?

Comment: @iWheelBuy you can certainly copy the strings in this scenario. post some code and point out the obstacles you're facing.

Comment: Hey Justin, I have just understood the whole @property thing! Everything works! Thanks for pointing out at the "property" issue!